# Handling call back URL without using serverlts

Tags: java, instagram

I am trying to get callback url using java HttpURLConnection for example I have registered client app in instagram and given access permission to client app.
If I will make a authorization call instagram api using HttpURLConnection it will sends response to my registered call back URL along code parameter value. Now I want that call back url with code? Is it possible to get that with out using servlets?

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to use servlets?

Comment: I want to test it locally without using any server that means can we authenticate Instagram without using redirectURL?